# Switching <div> content with fade in and fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="div1">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit.</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">Sit Dolor Ipsum Lorem.</div>
```

I have a html that contains the code above, And want to add a hyperlink that will change the content of `div1` into `div2` content. how to solve this?

**Algorithm:**

1. div1 fade out
2. div1 content = div2 content
3. div1 fade in

**I found this code (failed)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeOut();
    $("#div1").html(document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML);
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
});});
```

*But I would prefer hyperlink rather than the button.

Comment: Is JQuery acceptable?

Comment: @Anik : I've tried to use jQuery but the content of "div1" changed to "div2" content before it dissapeared (FadeOut)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Sure if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery, the following should work:

```js
// when link is clicked
$("#load").click(function (event) {
  // prevent page from refreshing
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // fade out
  // and wait for animation to finish
  $("#div1").fadeOut().promise()
  // once finished, execute the following function
  .done(function () {
    // copy HTML
    $("#div1").html($("#div2").html())
    // fade in
    .fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit.</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">Sit Dolor Ipsum Lorem.</div>
<a href="#" id="load">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, it's as easy as 1-2-3

Just call the fadeOut of the first object, and in the callback, fadeIn the second one

```
var time = 500; // number of milliseconds
$('#div1').fadeOut(time,function(){
  $('#div2').fadeIn(time);
});
```